# Prevent/catch a SWIG-wrapped module from exiting Python session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig, triangulation

On using a function in an imported module (C++ wrapped with swig) which appears to call [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html), it will sometimes fail.

The problem is that no Python exception is raised - after an error message string, it quits to the terminal, and code following that function call is not given a chance to run. i.e. something like:

```
import useful_module
# Do stuff here
useful_module.funtion_that_includes_call_to_triangle()  # This crashes under certain conditions
### cleanup code here not run... outputs error below ###

# Internal error in segmentintersection():
#   Topological inconsistency after splitting a segment.
#   Please report this bug to jrs@cs.berkeley.edu
#   Include the message above, your input data set, and the exact
#     command line you used to run Triangle.
```

I've tried to surround the offending line with a `try/except` but as it exits without raising an error, it isn't caught.

It will also exit back to the terminal if the above is tried in an `ipython` session.

Is there a way I can catch it quitting my python session so that my code continues?

Answer (score 0):

For now, my solution is to wrap the call inside a worker function and start the worker function as a new process using `multiprocessing.Process`. Data can be passed and returned in my case using Queues. Passing back exceptions caused by the code was tricky - I ended up wrapping the whole code block with a `try/except` and `put` the result in the return queue. If there is a better way, please leave a comment or answer.

I've included some implementation, in case it's useful.

Something like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import useful_module

# A serialisable worker function
def worker(q, other_args):
    try:
        # Do stuff here with usual try/except/raise
        results = useful_module.funtion_that_includes_call_to_triangle()
        q.put(results)
    except Exception as e:
        q.put(e)

q = mp.Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(q, other_args))
p.start()
p.join()

# Get results from worker
try:
    results = q.get(block=False)
except queue.Empty:
    print('No result. Triangle probably failed!')
    # Do failure handling here
else:
    # Check if an exception was raised by worker code
    if isinstance(results, Exception):
        raise results

# Continue as normal
```

In the event that the crash is triggered, it only kills off the newly created worker process, and the parent python process survives.